# Can function return object in c++? If yes, how? If no, why?

Tags: c++, function, object

Can function return an object in C++?

Comment: Yes.  `some_type foo() { return some_type; }`

Comment: @DebashisBarman Did you do *any* research before asking this question? Is there anything that makes you think the answer is ‘no’?

Answer (score 1):

> Can function return an object in C++?

Yes, any copyable or movable object type can be a function return type.

> If yes, how to return an object from a function?

With a return statement that gives the value of the object.

```
int f() {return 42;}
```